# Sharepointplus/Jquery: With 10%-20% chance not works as expected, but dunno why UPDATED

Tags: list, javascript, jquery, sharepointplus

**Situation:** I have a list with 2 columns (`ActYear` and `LastNumber`). Both column conatains only 1 number element. The `ActYear` contains the current year and the `LastNumber` is the number of items created this year.

**How should my code works:** When the user click on the "save" button the script get the number from `ActYear` and compare to the current year. If the number is not to same that means this is the first process of the new year so it refresh the `ActYear` to the current year and reset the `LastNumber` to 1. But if this is not to first process of the year simply need to update the `LastNumber` with +1.

**What happens if I run:** I belive the new year part of the `if` working fine or I didn't test enough time to get an error. But if I test the simply +1 side of the `if` I have about 10-20% chance that the `LastNumber` field ll be not updated. I don't get the reason why fail sometime. Also if I wanna use brutal force to test it and put the whole +1 upgrade into a `for` 100 time to see how many % is the unsuccesful process it is not works at all (or if run not update or only very rarely). (Maybe .get() not work many time in a row). Also I don't get any error message on the console, or it vanish so fast I can't see it. (When I press the "save" it go to the default list view page from the new view)

**UPDATE:**
I simplified the code based on the tips and after testing sharepointplus quite a lot. Now I have about 30% chance to fail still don't get why not any error and fail randomly.

**UPDATE2:**
I tested the new year part of the `If` about 30 time, but I didn't got any error. I changed the +1 part to create a variable with the math part and the update give the `LastNumber` that value of the variable. This way fails only about 5% of the time. So adding number to number inside the update process was related to have about 30% fail rate. But 5% is still a problem it have to be perfect.

**UPDATE3:** I added an alert after the variable generation. After about 40 test I noticed, the alert sometime not appear or the number in the alert shows the default number of the `LastNumber` not the `LastNumber+1`. So I guess the program is doing all the work parallel and sometime the alert fire when the +1 is not calculated yet or the update finish before the alert or the calcualtion. So looks like I have to ensure somehow the correct order. So the update must be run after the calculation done. Can u tell me, how to force that?

```
    function PreSaveAction()
{
$(function ()
{
  $SP().list("TargetList","http://.../sites/Registry/").get(
  {
    where: "ID=1"  //get the first row only, I have only 1 row so this gets everything :)
  },
  function getData(data)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      if((Number(data[i].getAttribute("ActYear"))) < (Number(new Date().getFullYear())))
      {
        $SP().list("IktatoKonyvLista","http://.../sites/Registry/").update(
        [{ID:1, ActYear: Number((new Date()).getFullYear())}, {ID:1, LastNumber: Number("1")}]);
      }
      else
      {
          var calc = (Number(data[i].getAttribute("LastNumber"))+Number("1"));
          alert(calc);
          $SP().list("TargetList","http://.../sites/Registry/").update(
          {ID:1, Sorszam: calc}); 
      }
    }
  });
});
    return true;
}
```

I am using jquary and sharepointplus. I am a beginer with both so it can be a trivial mistake. If u have any tips what to test or how to make is "fail safe" pls let me know! Thank you very much for your kind help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a synchronized function (`preSaveAction()`) with an asynchronize code (your requests against the server).

It's why it doesn't work.

You should use [this blog post](https://blog.kodono.info/wordpress/2016/11/18/execute-action-before-saving-a-form-and-after-form-validation-sharepoint/) that explains what to do to proceed with async code before saving a Sharepoint form.
I'll recopy the code from the blog post and mix it with your code:

```
// this function will execute your code
function beforeSaving() {
  var deferred=jQuery.Deferred();
  // your code here
  // please note that "http://.../sites/Registry/" is not required if the list "TargetList" is into the same website
  $SP().list("TargetList","http://.../sites/Registry/").get({where:"ID=1"}, function getData(data) {
    // your request will return 1 item because you use "ID=1"
    // so I change a bit your code:
    if (data.length===1) {
      if((Number(data[0].getAttribute("ActYear"))) < (Number(new Date().getFullYear()))) {
        // The params for Update should be different.... Let me fix it:
        $SP().list("IktatoKonyvLista","http://.../sites/Registry/").update({ID:1, ActYear: Number((new Date()).getFullYear()), LastNumber: Number("1")}, {
          after:function() {
            // you now need to indicate the operation has been completed:
            deferred.resolve();
          }
        });
      } else {
        var calc = (Number(data[0].getAttribute("LastNumber"))+Number("1"));
        alert(calc);
        $SP().list("TargetList","http://.../sites/Registry/").update({ID:1, Sorszam:calc}, {
          after:function() {
            // you now need to indicate the operation has been completed:
            deferred.resolve();
          }
        }); 
      }
    }
  });
  return deferred;
}

// force PostBackRequired to true in the context, otherwise it won't work if you open the into a modal
// Please note that "WPQ2FormCtx" may change depending of your server...
// Look at the source code of your page to find "FormCtx" and verify this variable is correct
WPQ2FormCtx.PostBackRequired=true;

// we override SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm
SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm=function(b){
  var a=SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.GetClientForm(b);
  var res = (a!=null&&a.SubmitClientForm());
  // if the form is not valid, then res===true
  if (res === true) return true;
  else {
    // if the form is valid we now want to do our asynchronous check
    beforeSaving().done(function() {
      // our test is valid too so we can send the form to the server
      WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions($get(WPQ2FormCtx.SubmitButtonID).name, "", true, "", "", false, true))
    }).fail(function() {
      // if it fails we just unblock the save button
      $get(WPQ2FormCtx.SubmitButtonID).disabled=false;
    })
  }
  // to make sure the form won't be submitted yet
  return true;
};
```

Comment: WoW. Thank you very much for the detailed comments it is rly worked well! Just I need to analize a bit more to understand every aspect ot this code. And thank you for creating sharepointplus, it makes everything easier! :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the

```
$(document).ready(function ()
```

And the opening and closing braces and parens. This does not belong here. This is a jquery function call that executes code when a page is finished loading. That’s not what you need here - the page is already loaded.

Also, what’s the point of “if (true)”?

Comment: I updated the code based on your tips and some testing. Pls take a look. And thanks you very much for your help!

Comment: I have not used the SP library you are using (I use SPServices). Are the $SP calls asynchronous? If so that could be the source of your inconsistency. Is there an option to make them synchronous or use something like promises?

Comment: Yeah in the end I figured out I should use .then() to solve this.